# Centering a navigation list

Tags: html, css, html-lists, nav

I am having a little trouble centering my nav items.
The exact problem is that on the left, there is a little whitespace that does not respond to my `:hover` nor do my lists center with `text-align:center` on my nav!

```css
   /* CORE ELEMENTS */
* {
 margin: 0;
 font-family: "Open Sans", Times New Roman;
 font-size: 1em; /* 16px is standaard, als je bv. 24px wilt doe je dus 24/16 = 1.5em */
}
html, body{
 height: 100%;
 margin: 0 auto;
}
footer{
 /**/
}
header{
}
   /* PSEUDO-CLASSES */
a:link {

}
a:visited {

}

a:hover {
 color: #F9F9F9;

}

a:active { 
 color: #171717;
    background-color: #F9F9F9;
}
nav ul li:hover {
    background-color: lightblue;
}
   /* STYLE ELEMENTS */
h1 {
 font-size: 2em;
}

h2 {
 font-size: 1.8em;
}
img {
 display: block;
}
   /* NAV, UL, LI, A */
nav {
 clear: both;
 background-color: #F9F9F9;
 text-align: center;
}
nav ul li{
 list-style-type: none;
 line-height: 5vh;
 width: 33vw;
 display: table-cell;
}
ul {
 border: 1px solid #EEEEEE;
}
a {
 text-decoration: none;
 color: black;
}
   /* HTML ELEMENTS */
section {
  height: 100vh;
}
section:nth-child(1) {
  background: lightblue;
}
section:nth-child(2) {
  background: lightgreen;
}
section:nth-child(3) {
  background: purple;
}
section:nth-child(4) {
  background: red;
}
section:nth-child(5) {
  background: yellow;
}
   /* CLASS & ID */
```

```html
<h1>WhiteWizard</h1> 
<nav>
    <ul>
        <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">About</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Contact</a></li>
    </ul>
</nav>
```

Comment: Could you please reproduce the issue in a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/)

Comment: why do your `li`'s have a style of `display: table-cell;`?

Comment: You can also post only relevant part of your styles.css in your question. "Stupid website" prevents to ask questions with thousands of lines of code ;)

Comment: I tried to reduce code but it just pasted it (with ctrl+k) as regular text...nothing fancy i posted and my li's had table cell because i want the full height filled with a color on :hover but that did not work without table-cell added

http://jsfiddle.net/bhqgbmh2/

Comment: Gandoe, if you use chrome and right click a specific area of your web page, then select 'inspect element' it will help you troubleshoot these issues much easier.  It's a great tool, and will definitely come in handy for future homework assignments.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just add

```
nav ul{
  padding: 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Add the following code to remove that 'whitespace':

```
ul
{
 padding: 0;   
}
```

fiddle here:  http://jsfiddle.net/yyetw0dm/